# ResearchKit: Change choices based on previous response

Tags: ios, researchkit

Im working on Survey app using ResearchKit and I need to change the values of the next question based on the previous response. Example:

```
Question 1: How many cars do you have?
- 1 Car
- 2 Cars
- 3 Cars
- 4 Cars
- xx Cars

Question 2: Which is your favorite car?
 - car number 1
 - car number 2
 - car number 3
 - car number 4
 - car number XX
```

The number of options of the question 2 will based on the value selected on Question 1.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution, while it is not possible to create new steps after you presented the ViewController, It is possible to update **answerFormat** of a step using a new array

```
for(ORKQuestionStep* step in ((ORKOrderedTask*)self.task).steps) {
            if([step.answerFormat isKindOfClass:[ORKValuePickerAnswerFormat class]]) {
               step.answerFormat = [[ORKValuePickerAnswerFormat alloc] initWithTextChoices:arrayOfChoices];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`ORKNavigableOrderedTask`](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/ResearchKit/Common/ORKNavigableOrderedTask.h). (See `ORKTest` for an usage example.)

Basically, you'd define individual steps for all the different options on the first question, and then conditionally navigate to the appropriate step based on its answer.

Comment: That is a good option, but I could not use it, since the user could have an infinite number of cars and I could not produce a step of each option.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira : have you found any solution ? ResearchKit looks more like static solution then dynamic solution as you have mentioned !

Comment: see my answer bellow @BishalGhimire

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
func step(after step: ...) and
func step(before step: ...)
```

Using these you can create the steps themselves on-the-fly.
However you also lose some other functionality and have to manage all the navigation yourself.